# How do I see that function $e^{-4x}$ is not bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

How do I see that function $e^{-4x}$ is not bounded? How do I proove that?

Comment: Consider the limit

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Do you know what the graph of this function looks like?

Comment: Check the limit to $-\infty$

Comment: $e^z\geq 1+z$ holds for any $z\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4):

it is bounded from below, since $e^t>0$ always.

Fix $M>0$ and take $x=-\frac{1}{4}\ln(2M)$, then $e^{-4x}=2M>M$ what proves that your function is not bounded from above.

Answer (score 0):

Every time $x$ **decreases** by $1/4$, then $-4x$ decreases by $1$, so $e^{-4x}$ gets multiplied by $e$, which is more than $2$.  Thus every time $x$ decreases by $1/4$, the quantity $e^{-4x}$ more than doubles.  If you keep doubling it over and over again, it approaches $\infty$, so it is unbounded.